# can't uploading an images in topic. nopCommerce mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

[image][image]When i try to add image in topic(local is working) on server(doesn't work),through insert `image->source` image in `Image/Content/Uploaded`, picture is attached in folder, but on page isn't showing picture.

I use nopcommerce 3.80.

Permissions are set in folder,in ACl admin has all privileges.

I'm missing something in code?

Comment: @Div thanks for your support!

Comment: You're welcome! Sara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.my project was added as sub domain in domain and the path was www.site.com/site and image uploader was looking for www.site.com/Content/uploaded not www.site.com/site/Content/uploaded